# SQL to squash rows based on dates

Tags: sql

I have a table of data like :

```
CategoryID    CustomerID    FromDate    ToDate
1             A             10/1/15     20/2/15
2             A             5/1/15      10/1/15
3             C             3/2/15      12/2/15
4             C             5/3/15      20/2/15
5             C             10/3/15     25/2/15
```

I need to squash/group by customer, taking the minimum FromDate and maximum ToDate, and the maximum CategoryID.

```
CategoryID    CustomerID    FromDate    ToDate
2             A             5/1/15      20/2/15 
5             C             3/2/15      25/2/15
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `GROUP BY` is your friend.  Give it a shot and come back here and tell us whether it worked.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: How do you want to squash them? With an anvil or a bus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CategoryID, t.CustomerID, MIN(FromDate), MAX(ToDate)
FROM Table1 as t
INNER JOIN (SELECT CustmerID as CustomerId,MAX(CategoryID) as MaxCategoryID FROM Table1 GROUP BY CustomerID) as a 
ON t.CustomerID=a.CustomerID and CategoryId=a.MaxCategoryID
GROUP BY t.CustomerID, CategoryID
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a very simple aggregate with a grouping on your CustomerId.

```
Select  Max(CategoryId) As CategoryId, 
        CustomerId, 
        Min(FromDate)   As FromDate, 
        Max(ToDate)     As ToDate
From    Table
Group By CustomerId
```